# Python request only a certain number of bytes

Tags: python, python-requests, byte, gif

I'm requesting GIF files from a URL and I'm trying to avoid downloading the whole file by only reading the bytes of the first frame. Is there a way using the requests or urllib.request module that allows you to only request/download a certain number of bytes?

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/712243005519560736/908229068909068318/sample_1.gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open image first and use `img.n_frames` it

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
img.n_frames
```

Ouptut

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [requests.Response.iter_content](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) to iterate over the response data.

An example to read the first 10 bytes to extract the width and
height of a GIF image:

**Test:**

```
import struct

import requests

URL = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/712243005519560736/908229068909068318/sample_1.gif"


def main():
    with requests.get(URL, stream=True) as r:
        header = next(r.iter_content(chunk_size=10))
        typ, version, width, height = struct.unpack("<3s3sHH", header)

        print(typ, version, width, height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py 
b'GIF' b'89a' 10 10
```

With this approach you will of course need to know the bytes offset
and size for the frame you want to read.